# Quantlib simulating options with different evaluation dates

Tags: options, programming, quantlib, heston

Im given a dataset of option data that looks like this.

```
df:
   start      exp     strike
2013-12-27 2014-01-30 10000
2013-12-27 2014-01-30 10500
2013-12-27 2014-01-30 11500
2014-01-31 2014-02-26 11000
2014-01-31 2014-02-26 12000
2014-01-31 2014-02-26 10000
2014-02-27 2014-03-27 12000
2014-02-27 2014-03-27 13000
2014-02-27 2014-03-27 14000
    .          .        .
    .          .        .
    .          .        .
```

df contains the start & expiration dates and the strike prices of option contracts. My goal is to simulate the option prices per contract. In order to do this, I also simulate the underlying prices using the Heston model. But first I needed to calibrate its parameters using the code below

```
import QuantLib as ql
daycount = ql.Actual365Fixed()
calendar  -ql.UnitedStates()
class Heston(ql.HestonModel):
    def __init__(self,yield_ts, dividend_ts,spot,p,strikes,vol,end, init_params):
        self.init_params=init_params
        self.dividend_ts = dividend_ts
        self.yield_ts = yield_ts
        self.spot =spot 
        self.strikes = strikes
        self.vol =vol
        self.p = p
        self.end = end
        theta, kappa, sigma, rho, v0 = self.init_params
        process=ql.HestonProcess(yield_ts, dividend_ts, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(spot)), v0, kappa, theta, sigma, rho)
        super().__init__(process)
        self.engine = ql.AnalyticHestonEngine(self)
        self.vol_surf = ql.HestonBlackVolSurface(ql.HestonModelHandle(self), self.engine.Gatheral)
        self.build_helpers()
               
    def build_helpers(self):
        '''
        Setup the helpers of Heston model based on the following input parameters;
        1. Term structures - yield_ts, dividend_ts
        2. Stock price at expiration date - spot
        3 Week Period between start and end of option contract  - p
        4. Strike - strikes
        5. Implied volatility - vol
        6. parameters- init_params  
        '''

        temp=[]
        self.grid_data = []
        for i, s in enumerate(self.strikes):
            v = self.vol[i]
 
            temp.append( ql.HestonModelHelper(self.p, calendar, int(self.spot), int(s), ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(float(v))), 
                                              self.yield_ts, self.dividend_ts)  )
 
            self.grid_data.append((self.end,s))
        for x in temp: x.setPricingEngine(self.engine)
        self.helpers=temp 
        self.loss= [x.calibrationError() for x in self.helpers]


for i, (start,exp) in enumerate(zip(df.start.values, df.exp.values)):
    calculation_date = ql.Date(start.day,start.month,start.year)
    expiration_date = ql.Date(exp.day,exp.month,exp.year) 
    
    strikes = df.strikes.loc[df.exp == exp]
    underlying_price = underlying[exp]
    implied_volatility = implied[exp]
    risk_free_rate = riskrate[exp]
    dividend_yield = dividendrate[exp]
    ##Creating term structures## 
    yield_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, risk_free_interest, dayCount)) 
    dividend_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(calculation_date,dividend_yield, dayCount))

    t = calendar.businessDaysBetween(calculation_date, expiration_date)
    p = ql.Period(t, ql.Days)
    # build the heston helpers to be used for calculation
    h = Heston(yield_ts,dividend_ts,underlying,p,dum.strikes.values,
            dum.imp.values,expiration_date,init_params=params)
```

`underlying`,`implied`,`riskrate`, and `dividendrate` are dictionaries that contain the information per expiration date of a contract. After this process, I use some optimization techniques to get the parameters. Im kinda confused because since im calibrating the parameters of heston per option contract then does this mean that the behavior of the underlying stock price will also be different? Is this the right process to do it? If not, please someone enlighten me.

Comment: What do your `start` and `expiry` dates mean, exactly? The `start` date confuses me a bit... if we're sitting at $t_0$ now and the strikes are all defined, then the options have all already started. Or are you saying we wait until the `start` date before buying the option? In that case, you'll need a heston vol surface for each `start` date (maybe this is what you're doing in your code, but it's not obvious to me)

Comment: @StackG  Yup, we need to wait until the ```start``` to buy the option. So what you are saying is every option contract I need to calibrate the heston model?

Comment: Not every option, but every start date (options with the same start date can be priced from the same surface)

Comment: Oh I get it now thank you